# Ubuntu does not run after installation

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu on a new Lenovo G480. I downloaded the .iso file and burned CD to install. The computer had no OS pre-installed, I used the CD installer to install Ubuntu 12.04. After installation, when I turn on the computer, Ubuntu does not start up. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Does it show `Operating System not found` or just gives a blank screen? Please describe what you see.

Answer (score 1):

refer the ubuntu installtion guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest